# Getting window.confirm to work

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

I am trying to get window.confirm to work with a script I am working with however it doesn't seem to wanna work . What happens is if the person presses cancel it still runs the code, And sadly now the way i wrote the code the popup box won't even show up in chrome. Not sure why though I can remove the window.confirm method and it will still show a popup box but it will just run the script regardless of which choice you make. Here is the code , Thank you for your assistance.

```
var validNavigation = false;

function wireUpEvents() {

var dont_confirm_leave = 0; to be able to leave withou confirmation
var leave_message = 'Leaving the page will terminate your Self-Service or Kiosk session.';

function goodbye(e) {
if (!validNavigation) 

    function goodbye() = {
    var x = window.confirm("Leaving the page will terminate your Self-Service or Kiosk session.")
    if (x)
    {
    window.onunload=leave;
    }    
    else            {
    return "" ;
    }
    }}

function leave() {
    if (!validNavigation) {
    killSession();
    }
    }

    //set event handlers for the onbeforeunload and onunloan events
    window.onbeforeunload=goodbye;
    //window.onunload=leave;

            }
    // Wire up the events as soon as the DOM tree is ready
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    wireUpEvents();
    });
```

Comment: Spend more time cleaning up your code. If it's hard to read, it's hard to debug.

Comment: Well noted and will attempt to execute better in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't stop someone from leaving the page - if they want to leave, they can.  Stopping this event from propogating in the usual fashion doesn't work.  The way to get a popup message to display (which will usually be surrounded by browser supplied text) is to return your string from the function fired by onbeforeunload.  Try this:

```
function goodbye() {
  if (!validNavigation)
    return "Are you sure you want to leave";
  else
    return "";
}
window.onbeforeunload = goodbye;
```

Comment: Its not so much as leave its that if they press cancel and don't leave the code that i only want to run if they DID leave would still run which is not something i want to happen. But i will try out your suggestion and just shorten it out.

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax errors in your code. Here is your code reformatted, and as you can see you are not closing your functions properly:

```
var validNavigation = false;

function wireUpEvents() {
    var dont_confirm_leave = 0;
    var leave_message = document.getElementById("kioskform:broswerCloseSubmit");
    var leave_safari = document.getElementById("kioskform:broswerCloseSafari");

    function goodbye(e) {
        if (!validNavigation) {
            function disp_confirm() {
                var leaveMessage = confirm("Are you sure you want to leave")
                if (leaveMessage == true) {
                    if (dont_confirm_leave !== 1) {
                        if (!e) e = window.event;
                        //for IE
                        e.cancelBubble = true;
                        e.returnValue = leave_message.click();
                        //e.stopPropagation works in Firefox.
                        if (e.stopPropagation) {
                            e.stopPropagation();
                            e.preventDefault();
                        }
                        //return works for Chrome and Safari
                        leave_safari.click();
                        return '';

                        //add the code to delete the kiosk information here.
                        // this is what is to be done.
                    }
                } else {
                    alert("Returning to the page.")
                }
            }}
            window.onbeforeunload = goodbye;

            // Attach the event keypress to exclude the F5 refresh
            jQuery('document').bind('keypress', function(e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 116) {
                    validNavigation = true;
                }
            });
            // Attach the event click for all links in the page
            jQuery("a").bind("click", function() {
                validNavigation = true;
            });
            // Attach the event submit for all forms in the page
            jQuery("form").bind("submit", function() {
                validNavigation = true;
            });
            // Attach the event click for all inputs in the page
            jQuery("input[type=submit]").bind("click", function() {
                validNavigation = true;
            });
        }
        // Wire up the events as soon as the DOM tree is ready
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            wireUpEvents();
        });
```

Update: Updated the code don't know if there are still syntax errors or not but. Any other errors I am missing?

Comment: Plus, it's `alert`, not `Alert`. Unless it's another way of alerting the user.

Comment: Okay I can see the Capital A in alert being wrong. I dont notice the syntax errors as much nor the closing of functions but I will take your word on it. So your saying thats why the code isn't working?